# "Input Sources..." doesn't work in Mavericks?

Tags: keyboard, macos, remote-desktop

Since upgrading to Mavericks, the input sources option changed, and moved to the keyboard control panel.  That's fine, but selecting the "Input Sources..." button in the Keyboard tab of the Keyboard panel does absolutely nothing!  (No error message is displayed either.) Any ideas what could be causing this or how to troubleshoot it?

The only thing I can consider that might be unusual is that I only access this machine by remote desktop.

Comment: Could you maybe post a screenshot? I can't find any button labeled  "Input Sources…" in the Keyboard tab of the keyboard control panel.

Comment: I see the Input Sources button and for me it works. This is not running via remote desktop, though, so that might make a difference.

Comment: This kind of thing is often caused by a bad .plist file in Home/Library/Preferences.  Which one is the question.

Comment: @Asmus Input Sources is now one of 4 tabs under System Preferences/Keyboard.  It can also be reached via a button at the bottom of System Preferences/Language & Region. Not the same as 10.8 and earlier.

Comment: @TomG ah, okay, I misunderstood the question in that regard. Noah: I'm wondering, does the remote computer you're connecting to a physical keyboard attached?